# get cursor x and y values with a click listener on Javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I need a the x and y values of the cursor when the user clicks on the canvas. I have looked all over the internet and found many different ways to do this, yet I believe they don't work because I clear and update the canvas with frames. I was able to get key clicks to work though.

I just learning code and need lots of explanation.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
var canvas_area = {
canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
start : function() {
    this.canvas.width = canvas_width;
    this.canvas.height = canvas_height;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.frameNo = 0;
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        canvas_area.keys = (canvas_area.keys || []);
        canvas_area.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
    })
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        canvas_area.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");            
    })
    canvas.addEventListener('onmousedown', function(event) {
        canvas_area.cursor_position = event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY;
    })
},
stop_bar : function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
},    
clear : function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
}
}

function updateGameArea() {
     canvas_area.clear();

     if (canvas_area.keys && canvas_area.keys[27]) {alert("pause");}//press escape key to use (27 is the escape key)
     if (canvas_area.cursor_position){
         alert(canvas_area.cursor_position);
     }//does not work
```

Answer (score 1):

if you change from "onmousedown" to "mousedown" it should work.

Check my fiddle on jsbin

http://jsbin.com/pimeri/81/edit?html,css,js,output

```
var elem = document.getElementById('canvas');

elem.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  var x =  parseInt(event.pageX - elem.offsetLeft );
  var y =  parseInt(event.pageY - elem.offsetTop );
})

elem.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event){
  var x =  parseInt(event.pageX - elem.offsetLeft );
  var y =  parseInt(event.pageY - elem.offsetTop );
})

elem.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event){
  var x =  parseInt(event.pageX - elem.offsetLeft );
  var y =  parseInt(event.pageY - elem.offsetTop );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas_area.canvas.addEventListener("click", getClickPosition, false);
function getClickPosition(e){
var xPosition = e.clientX;
    var yPosition = e.clientY;
return {x: xPosition, y: yPosition}
}
```

Comment: Since the canvas element is rarely at [0,0] in the window, you must also account for the offset position of the canvas element vs the window using `canvas.getBoundingClientRect`.